# Configuring Loki Datasource for Grafana - Error no Org id found

Tags: grafana-loki

While configuring Loki data source for Grafana you might get the error "no org id found"

Answer (score 6):

You need to added the HTTP header `X-Scope-OrgID` with some value say "test"

Details https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/operations/authentication/

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Or you can just set `loki.auth_enabled: false` in your helm chart values / loki config